# Dplyr filter based on less than equal to condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to subset a data based on `<=` logic using `dplyr` in `R`. Even after running `filter` function, the data is not being filtered.

How can I fix this?

Code

```
library(tidyverse)
    
value = c("a,b,c,d,e,f")
Year = c(2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020)
Month = c(01,01,12,12,07,07)
dummy_df = data.frame(value, Year, Month)
dummy_df = dplyr::filter(dummy_df, Month <=07)
```

Now on a `dummy` data frame this does work, but when I use this function on an actual data set with in which I created `Year`, `Month` and `Day` columns using `lubridate`; I still see data from months greater than `07`.

Comment: If yoyu are using `<= 7` what do you expect

Comment: i.e. you have only two values 1 and 7, and thus less than or equal to include both 1 and 7

Comment: Please note that `07` with prefix 0 is still numeric unless you have an actual string `"07"`, then the filter is different

Comment: Yes, that was a careless mistake (thank you for pointing that out) while creating a sample data frame for the question; I have updated my question to explain what's really going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be because the OP's original dataset may be having 'Month' as `character` column.  Convert to `numeric` and it should work

```
dummy_df = dplyr::filter(dummy_df, as.numeric(Month) <= 7)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the issue, good to know that `lubridate` creates `character` columns.

Comment: @Mandalorian it could be something from `format` which returns the 2 digit month

Comment: I didn't mean to use `subset` wanted to try this with base R's `Filter` but apparently these two are not quite the same.

Answer (score 2):

Or in base R we could do:

```
subset(dummy_df, as.numeric(Month) <= 7)

        value Year Month
1 a,b,c,d,e,f 2020     1
2 a,b,c,d,e,f 2020     1
5 a,b,c,d,e,f 2020     7
6 a,b,c,d,e,f 2020     7
```